# How to get simply email address after MimeUtility.decodeText()?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

How can I simply get the email address after use MimeUtility.decodeText() from javax.mail.internet ?

After that operation I have following String: 
    `Foo Bar <foo.bar@abc.en>`

I can do that by methods from String class but I'm interested in existed predefinied method for this ?

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to define your method. To get the String you only need one line of code:

```
String email = stringToDecode.split("<")[1].substring(0, stringToDecode.split("<")[1].length() - 1);
```

Comment: I know but if I'll define my own method I have to write unit test, etc... :)

Comment: This sort of "hack" was the only way that I found while trying to solve the same problem

Comment: You have a bug here... ;) Do you know where ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Just call `new InternetAddress(addr).getAddress()`.  In fact, you don't even need to call `MimeUtility.decodeText()` first.